# "Live Count" options in Select

Tags: javascript, html-select

How do i can count the Number of option Tags in the this code below with JS (without the use of JQuery

```
<select name="torso" id="torso">
      <option value="0" selected="">all</option>
      <option value="1">1-3</option>
      <option value="2">4-7</option>
      <option value="3">8-11</option>
      <option value="4">&gt;=12</option>
</select>
```

In this case the result should be 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
var x = document.getElementById("torso").options.length;
console.log(x); //prints 5
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/hDyuW/

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
var number = document.getElementById('torso')    // pick <select>
               .getElementsByTagName('option')   // pick all <option>'s
               .length;
```